# Visual Studio Code replaces console.log()

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

**Visual Studio Code** randomly (50 percents of cases) replaces the `console.log(` with `console(` in JavaScript (ES6, Vanilla). All settings are set by default, no shortcuts or extensions used.

Have anybody experienced this behaviour?

[image: Demonstration]

[image: Version]

Comment: @JaromandaX I totally agree, the MVSC tracker should have been searched first

Comment: @JaromandaX However, googling the "visual studio code replaces console.log" gives nothing, so please consider this question as the proxy for the issue.

Comment: I take it all back - apparently I should take the tour - as visual studio code is a "tool commonly used by programmers", it seems to be on topic - how strange that *"I found a bug in an old version of an IDE"* would actually be on topic! I've learned something today ... nothing useful, but something

Comment: @JaromandaX According to your profile description, your plan for today for "learn at least one thing every day of my life" is completed:)

Comment: touché - you got me there :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is followed by [issue 56026](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/56026)

> Can you try setting `editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter` to false and see if you still have this issue?

It is possibly solved in 1.27.1 (possibly without having to change that setting).